# retain jquery facebox centered when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I'm using jquery facebox dialogs, I'm trying to modify it to remain centered when I scroll, I'm not a programer although I know a bit of coding, I found this to open facebox on click coordinates

http://www.web-ramblings.co.uk/positioning-jquery-facebox-by-mouseclick/

I guess thats the same are to edit, what I'm trying to achieve is having facebox centered on the page even if I scrool down,

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to implement a window event for resize / scrolling. Instead of providing an answer to that can you not simply use [fancyBox](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://fancybox.net/&ei=eXEpTvSIK9GDhQeqnqT7Cw&usg=AFQjCNEbOcAGKYXbgAxypAxAVvCNE2lBAg&sig2=zv-HQldHXqJjvBICldhssQ) which already takes care of this for you?

Comment: fancybox does not retain the modal centered while scrollign down the page, at least in the examples. can you help?